# Preserve Word formatting in Announcements list

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation

One of our users would like an Announcements list that shows the contents of Word documents posted there, with new ones added weekly. The documents have screenshots with arrows and boxes drawn on them, and these can't be cut and pasted into the body of an announcement. What do you suggest?

My Plan B is to use a simple document list where the Summary column explains the contents of the current week's document.

Comment: Add a new RichText field to the Announcement list and use that for entering data.

Comment: I am thinking about the create a page with word document and then reference that page in the Announcement list. May be Blog or Article page?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use a blog instead and they can publish the content to the blog directly from Word and retain the look they have with no customizations necessary.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the blog idea, except that it saves the arrows and boxes above or below the screenshot. These should appear as overlays on the screenshot to highlight specific parts of the image. I could use CSS to reposition the objects, but I want the process to be as painless as possible for the blog editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the type of column that your event descritpion is. If you change it to a Rich-Text enabled column, then you can style text, add pcitures and links and what-all else.

To do that:
Open your Event Announcement list.
At the top ribbon, click the "List" tab.
Click "List Settings"
On the next page, you'll see your columns listed. Click on the title of the column that contains your descriptions.
Change its setting to "Multiple Lines of Text" and specify that the type of text is "Enhanced Rich Text."
Click ok, head back out to your list, and edit your items to your heart's content.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried copying the contents of the Word document and pasting these into the column, with the Enhanced Rich Text type, but this doesn't capture the pictures. I want to minimize the after-the-fact editing as much as possible for the people managing the announcements.

Comment: Try uploading the pictures rather than copying. I could add images by uploading from either my computer or a Sharepoint address. When I did a copy/paste, it did not work either.

Comment: That would work for the pictures, but not for the drawing objects in the document.

Comment: Turn the drawing objects into .jpg's : https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/picasa/SLYGUxuiKoc   Alternately you can right click a drawing, copy, then "Paste Special" and choose Picture. Once it's a picture, you can right click and go "Save as Picture".

Comment: The Publish to Blog function in Word converted the drawing objects to JPGs, but didn't allow me to overlay these onto the screenshot JPG.